# Comments not displaying in songs#show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The comments don't appear to be showing after they are submitted (created). If you look at [songs#show.html.erb](https://github.com/Apane/leap/blob/master/app/views/songs/show.html.erb) you'll see the comments code. Not sure why they aren't showing, I've looked into how Ryan Bates does his comments and my code is identical. Please advise :)

Note: for what it's worth I'm running rails 4.

Comment: 2.0.0p195 :002 > Song.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Song id: 2, title: "Jay Z - Picasso", artist: nil, bio: "N/A", track_file_name: "02_Picasso_Baby_-_Album_Version_(Explicit).mp3", track_content_type: "audio/mp3", track_file_size: 4919818, track_updated_at: "2013-07-13 08:48:48", user_id: nil, created_at: "2013-07-13 08:48:48", updated_at: "2013-07-13 08:48:48">]>

Comment: The problem is in your controllers. When you are creating a new comment it needs to belong to a song and therefore needs to be told the song_id of the song it belongs to. But this is not being done in your controller.

Comment: What's the result of `Comment.all`?

Comment: Althaf, how do I do this in the controller?

Comment: Michael,  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: 3, song_id: nil, author_name: "test", site_url: "test", content: "test", user_id: nil, created_at: "2013-07-14 01:58:17", updated_at: "2013-07-14 01:58:17">,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `song/show` variable `@song` is ok, but then you render `comments/_form` which uses `@comment` which is set to a new comment without `song_id` set.

Yo build a comment with song_id set to id of `@song` you could:

```
# songs_controller.rb
def show
  @comment = @song.comments.build
end
```

Comment: this can't be right, everytime I create a song a blank comment automatically gets created.

Comment: not created, just built. To actually hit database creating a new comment, it would be `@song.comments.create`. was this your concern?